# Heirarchical, in-memory associations without poor workmanship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a need for a nested, hierarchical data structure extracted by ActiveRecord, all early-loaded of course, that I can JSONify. `TaskSet`, `Task`, `Todo`, and `LineItem` are all associated as the latter being a child of the former. As is apparent, I am no Ruby genius: the best I've come up with is

```
   @hsh = TaskSet.all.
                  includes(:tasks => {:todos => :lineitems} ).
                  map{ |ts| ts => ts.tasks.
                    map{ |t| t => t.todos.
                      map{ |td| td => td.lineitems }}}.
                  as_json
```

This is dubiously-acceptable for very small N (for each level) and simply unusable for larger N. I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve recurring N+1 issues.

---

Bonus:

Is there a way to preempt the transliteration into another data structure and have AR eager-load all the down-depth associations in memory so that a `@task_set.as_json` would accomplish the same thing without hitting the database?

Comment: Is this happening within a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear where you're calling this code so this might not apply but I'm going to assume you're doing this within a controller. If that's the case, I would recommend the following approach

First in your controller, load all the TaskSets and eager-load the associated models

```
def index
  @task_sets = TaskSet.includes(tasks: { todos: :lineitems })
end
```

This will make 4 calls to the DB but will load all associated models into memory such that looping through the associations and inner associations won't result in more DB calls (i.e. no N+1 issues).

To construct the actual JSON, I would highly recommend using a JSON builder like [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). Since jbuilder comes with latest versions of Rails, I'll use that as an example

Create a jbuilder view under `app/views/task_sets/index.json.jbuilder` and construct the JSON you require.

```
json.array! @task_sets do |task_set|
  json.some_attribute task_set.some_attribute

  json.tasks task_set.tasks, :attribute_1, :attribute_2
  # ... #
end
```

Using a JSON builder gives you more control than simply calling `as_json`, especially in a case where you're including child objects. Hope this helps.

Comment: Huh! So... I have actually been using jbuilder for this from the outset, but only in a flat-iterative way with a bunch of nested `json.array! do`s duplicating the same performance as the `map` statements above. I never stopped to think that the `include` in the controller variable would still be closed over and "deep-dottedly" available in the json view template. Thx and Strong Work, this is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
@hsh = TaskSet.all
              .includes(:tasks => {:todos => :lineitems} )
              .joins(:tasks, :todos, :lineitems)
              .as_json
```

would do this.

It would make 1 DB query. I don't know how efficiently it can convert the data structure to JSON, or how many items are in the data structure.

See [Rails Guides Eager Loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

Here is an example that shows how to query associated models with a single DB query:
[Preload, Eagerload, Includes and Joins](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html)

Comment: @B Seven: the documentation is always the first place to go! This, however, is a deeper problem: the solution proposed above (like those in the docs) only returns a set of `TaskSet`s. I need the "full object," like so: `{tasksets: { ... , tasks: { ... , todos: { ... , lineitems: { ... } } } }`

Comment: Eager-loading doesn't use joins so this would actually perform multiple DB queries - one to get all task sets, another to load all tasks associated with the loaded task sets, another to load all todos associated with all loaded tasks, and a final query to load all line items associated with all loaded todos. Also, the `as_json` wouldn't include any of the child objects.

Comment: @codelinguist - The correct `includes` and `joins` clauses should pull all of the associated data in one DB query.

Comment: @B Seven, @BartJedrocha - Still the same problem, gentlemen. The `JOIN`, while combining result sets, can still only be mapped to single, existing AR Model, which remains a `TaskSet`. This is unfortunately quite a hairy problem I've spent a reasonable amount of time not solving. ;)

Comment: @codelinguist - It's not clear to me what is different between the `map` method in the question and the results from the query. The query should pull all the associated records with a TaskSet. Perhaps you can include an example of the desired output.

Comment: @B Seven - thanks for the update. This comes closer, but there's nothing in the API that I can find that will return a hierarchical result like that outlined in my first comment. Someone's had this problem before me; I'm am currently looking through the [amoeba](https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba) and [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable) gems. The former looks promising.

Comment: @codelinguist - Amoeba and deep_clonable are not for your issue. They are for cloning an object and its associated objects. The correct SQL query will pull an object and all of its associated object. `as_json` knows how to convert nested objects.

Comment: @B Seven - I must be missing something, then. I been in the Rails console testing everything and can't get any "deep love" past the @TaskSet root...

Comment: Can you add the console output to the question, along with your desired output?